# Does a subset consisting only of isolated points have a limit point?

Tags: general-topology

In a topological space, if all elements of a subset are isolated, will the subset have any limit point? If it does have a limit point, then the limit point must of course not belong to the subset. Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, it *can*. Look at the set $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$, where $n$ ranges over the positive integers, and the ambient space is the reals with the usual topology.  Of course, it is easy to come up with examples where a set with only isolated points has *no* limit point in the underlying space.